# The last point of potential destruction for the exception object

Tags: c++, exception, language-lawyer, destructuring

English is not my native language. So sometimes reading the C++ Standard I can not understand what is written.
And here is one such a misunderstanding.

In the C++ 20 Standard (14.1 Throwing an exception) there is written

> 4. ... The points of potential destruction for the exception object are:
>
> (4.1) — when an active handler for the exception exits by any means
> other than rethrowing, immediately after the destruction of the object
> (if any) declared in the exception-declaration in the handler;
>
> (4.2) — when an object of type std::exception_ptr (17.9.6) that refers
> to the exception object is destroyed, before the destructor of
> std::exception_ptr returns.

and then

> Among all points of potential destruction for the exception object,
> **there is an unspecified last one where the exception object is destroyed**. All other points happen before that last one.

What is "the last point of destruction"? What is there its meaning in the Standard?

It seems that there has been listed already all points of potential destruction for the exception object.

Comment: `All other points happen before that last one.` - haha, no kidding...

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I guess that's the "happens-before" defined in [Memory model](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model), in case an implementation wants to do some funky multithreading with its exceptions or something.

Comment: Probably. It was just the wording that I found amusing.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError yeah, this had me chuckle as well. Top-tier legalese :)

Comment: «Last one» means the point at «run time», not in the list.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer The exception object is a single object. So it can have only one point of potential destruction. And these points of potential destructions are described in 4.1 and 4.2. So what is the "unspecified last point"?!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow _The exception object is a single object. So it can have only one point of potential destruction._ It can have only one point of **actual** destruction, you did want to say. _what is the "unspecified last point"_ The point «where the exception object is destroyed».

Answer (score 2):

This is just a comically dense way to say:

> The exception object is allowed to die at these points: [...].
>
> One of these points will be the last one (duh), and at that point the exception will actually die.
>
> The implementation is free to order these points as it wants, as long as it can determine which one is last to kill the exception at the right time.

In other words, it does The Right Thing™.

Answer (score 0):

There may be multiple `std::exception_ptr` objects referring to the same exception used and destroyed in multiple threads. The standard says that it is unspecified which `std::exception_ptr` destructor invocation destroys the exception, but guarantees that all other destructor invocations happen before.